An error occurs when using SwiftUSD introduced by Swift Package Manager
I created an Xcode project and installed SwiftUSD with Swift Package Manager, which is linked below.
https://github.com/wabiverse/SwiftUSD/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file
However, after installing,
import PixarUSD

and tried to build the project with the default code when newly created, but before the code is built, many errors occur as follows.
Multiple commands produce '/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftUSDPackageCamera-gpbofwclcozunoespbordaiizrfp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Frameworks/Alembic_301B1C71A317B7B4_PackageProduct.framework'

Target 'Examples' (project 'SwiftUSD') has copy command from '/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftUSDPackageCamera-gpbofwclcozunoespbordaiizrfp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/Alembic_301B1C71A317B7B4_PackageProduct.framework' to '/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftUSDPackageCamera-gpbofwclcozunoespbordaiizrfp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Frameworks/Alembic_301B1C71A317B7B4_PackageProduct.framework'

Multiple commands produce '/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftUSDPackageCamera-gpbofwclcozunoespbordaiizrfp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Frameworks/Alembic_301B1C71A317B7B4_PackageProduct.framework/Alembic_301B1C71A317B7B4_PackageProduct'.....

In the Swift Package Manager,
“If there are files with the same name in multiple directories, each with the same name, an error will occur during build.”
which is what the search says about Swift Package Manager errors. Does the fact that such errors occur mean that I need to modify the file names after installing with Swift Package Manager, for example by changing them?
